# client recieves data as [object object]

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to send some objects back to client after connecting, but somehow they are receiving them as empty arrays `{}` when `List<T>` is sent and as `[object Object]` for

here is my hub code:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly List<User> Users = new List<User>();

    private const string DateTimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss tt zzz";

    public async Task Join(string username, UserType usertype, string locale, CallerInfo callerInfo)
    {
        // Add the new user
        var user = Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Username == username);
        if (user != null)
        {
            Users.Remove(user);
        }

        Users.Add(new User
        {
            Username = username,
            ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
            Type = usertype,
            Locale = locale,
            ConnectionStartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormat),
            CallerInfo = callerInfo
        });
        await SendUserListUpdate(StatusConstants.Join, usertype);
    }

    public async Task SendUserListUpdate(string status, UserType userType, string conID = "")
    {
        object[] args = { Users, status, conID == string.Empty ? Context.ConnectionId : conID, userType };
        await Clients.All.SendCoreAsync(MethodNameConstants.UpdateUserList, args);
    }
}
```

and here is my client code:

```js
"use strict";

var locale = 'ar-SA';
var username = 'test-user';
var usersList;


var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/MyHub").withAutomaticReconnect().build();

// register listeners
connection.on('UpdateUserList',
    function(users,status, connectionId, userType) {
        usersList = users;
        console.log(users);
        console.log(usersList);
        console.log('status : '+ status);
        console.log('connection id : '+ connectionId);
    });

// join client list
connection.start().then(async function () {
    console.log('trying to join users list');
    await connection.invoke('Join',username,'guest', locale, null);
    console.log('join successful');
}).catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
```

I am trying to receive correct objects on client side so that I can handle them correctly. I couldn't figure out why it is received like this

Comment: Why you are sending a generic object? You should create a model for what are you sending via SignalR both on server side and client side.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem.Maybe you could give a minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: @Kiril1512 the method `SendCoreAsync()` takes object as an argument

Comment: @XingZou this code sends `Users` , and it is received on client side as `{}` with no properties